# what is the difference between "string" == $variable and $variable == "string" in IF statements

Tags: php, wordpress

I am comparing a variable to a string in an "if" statement. There seems to be different results depending on if its $variable == "string" or "string" == $variable.

I don't seem to understand the difference. Any help in understanding would be appreciated.

```
$template = get_page_template_slug();
if('template.php' == $template || 'template_2.php' == $template  ){
wp_enqueue_style('masorny', 
get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/css/template.css', false, '1.1', 'all');}
```

vs

```
$template = get_page_template_slug();
if( $template == 'template.php' ||  $template == 'template_2.php'  ){
wp_enqueue_style('masorny', 
get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/css/template.css', false, '1.1', 'all');}
```

The first one works correctly the second one just shows up a blank page.

Comment: There's no big difference between the two and if one is failing you may simply have an error elsewhere that causes the blank page. Turn error reporting all the way up and check your logs to get the error message.

Comment: why would changing them around then cause the error? I see it in this piece of code that the error occurs, not in a different one.